# How to redirect to custom Vaadin Flow Login Route as login form in Spring Security Configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin-flow, loginview

I keep getting - Whitelabel Error Page, 404 Not Found - when trying to use a Vaadin Flow login form in Spring Security configuration.

I have followed some instructions on how to implement the Spring Security and configure for using a MySQL database for authentication - which are in line with how the Bakery example is configured.

https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egXtoL5Kg08&t=2288s

This is my Spring Security configuration

```java
package com.admEx.app.security;

import com.admex.demo.DAOs.UserDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


/**
 * Configures spring security, doing the following:
 * <li>Bypass security checks for static resources,</li>
 * <li>Restrict access to the application, allowing only logged in users,</li>
 * <li>Set up the login form,</li>
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserDAO.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/login";// + BakeryConst.PAGE_STOREFRONT;
    private static final String DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE = "/home";

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());

    }

    private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Require login to access internal pages and configure login form.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable() //

                // Register our CustomRequestCache that saves unauthorized access attempts, so
                // the user is redirected after login.
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache()) //

                // Restrict access to our application.
                .and().authorizeRequests()

                // Allow all flow internal requests.
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll() //

                // Allow all requests by logged in users.
                .anyRequest().authenticated() //

                // Configure the login page.
                .and().formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll() //
                .defaultSuccessUrl(DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE, true)
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL) //
                .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)

                // Configure logout
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    }

    /**
     * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring security.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                // Vaadin Flow static resources //
                "/VAADIN/**",

                // the standard favicon URI
                "/favicon.ico",

                // the robots exclusion standard
                "/robots.txt",

                // web application manifest //
                "/manifest.webmanifest",
                "/sw.js",
                "/offline-page.html",

                // (development mode) static resources //
                "/frontend/**",

                // (development mode) webjars //
                "/webjars/**",

                // (production mode) static resources //
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
    }

}
```

and here the loginView done by only Java

```java
@Tag("sa-login-view")
@SpringUI(path = "/login")
@Route(value = LoginView.ROUTE)
@PageTitle("Login")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {
    public static final String ROUTE = "login";

    private LoginForm login = new LoginForm(); //

    public LoginView(){
        login.setAction("login"); //
        getElement().appendChild(login.getElement()); //
    }
}
```

Comment: What 404 you have in your browser console? For what components? Also, have you tried to remove `@Tag("sa-login-view")
                                @SpringUI(path = "/login")` annotations? Or why are you adding them (doesn't feel correct)?

Comment: The error looks like
------
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat May 18 20:24:28 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
-------
I have tried removing those above, yes. It was taken straight from 
https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/form-based
Have also tried the other options they suggest

Comment: When I try to enter a second time the view shown is 
´´´
{"timestamp":"2019-05-18T18:40:49.503+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/login"}
´´´